# Wordpress Pages not working on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I copied my wordress site to an AWS instance. My home page is working fine, but the pages are not working properly. It is giving me a 404 error.

Not Found

The requested URL /some-page/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at example.com Port 80

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. In case it will help someone, here it is.

By default the Allowoveride is set to None.

1) Open /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

2) Locate "AllowOverride None" inside ''

3) Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"

4) Restart apache server

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons,
First check if the site is copied properly, compare the size of the website on both source and AWS.
Check if the permissions are same as source.
Check the error logs, u can share  logs